# Bootstrap Typeahead updater not working

Tags: jquery-autocomplete, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead

I try this:

```
$('input[name=recerv_country]').typeahead({
    remote : {
        url: '?country=%QUERY',
        filter: function(data) {
            var resultList = data.map(function (item) {   
                return item.name;
            });
            return resultList;
        }
    },
    updater : function (item) {
        //item = selected item
        //do your stuff.
        alert(item.name);
        alert('foo');
        alert('bar');
        //dont forget to return the item to reflect them into input
        return item;
    }
});
```

Nothing happens, alerts not appears. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 7):

```
$('input[name=recerv_country]').on('typeahead:selected', function(evt, item) {
    alert(item.value);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

With Twitter Bootstrap 3 the Typeahead plugin has been dropped. Bootstrap recommend to use https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js in stead. You seem to use typeahead.js cause you use the remote call. Typeahead.js hasn't a updater function.

Check the custom events section of https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js. `typeahead:selected` will fit your needs maybe.

See also: [Bootstrap 3 typeahead.js, use similar functions from Bootstrap 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131467/bootstrap-3-typeahead-js-use-similar-functions-from-bootstrap-2)